# How do I pass the value from a TextBox control into a SQL statment for the "FROM" clause

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to pass the value from a `TextBox` (`txtTableNumber.Text`) into my SQL for the "FROM" clause.

I am using the below code:

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSales.SelectedRows
        SQL.DataUpdate("DELETE FROM '" + txtTableNumber.Text + "' WHERE sl ="1" ")
    Next
End sub
```

Comment: Look into using parameters.

Comment: You can't use `WHERE sl= "1" "` but `sl='1'`... of course, if `sl` is string/text data type

Comment: @Bugs it's the table name what OP wants to take from the textbox, not any parameter (if i understand what OP wants)

Comment: What if user inputs 'sometable; drop sometable; --'? [Read Bobby Tables story](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @Pikoh yes I wanted value from the textbox.

Comment: @Pikoh, appreciate that but can still be done. Sonam, what is `SQL` declared as?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove the `'` around the table name and add it in the `sl` part:

```
SQL.DataUpdate("DELETE FROM " + txtTableNumber.Text + " WHERE sl ='1' ")
```

Anyway, you must be careful with this statement. If in your `txtTableNumber` someone writes `yourTableName;drop yourTableName; --` what would happen is that your table would be deleted. That's why is not recomended to create a dynamic string with the table name as a string. You should probably better use a case statement to validate the input,something like:

```
Select Case txtTableNumber.Text
    Case "Table1"
        SQL.DataUpdate("DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE sl ='1' ")
        Exit Select
    Case "Table2"
        SQL.DataUpdate("DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE sl ='1' ")
        Exit Select
   ...
End Select
```

Comment: @SeanLange You are all right. Edited to add an explanation and an alternative solution

Comment: @Pikoh thanks a lot for your help. really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're wide open to SQL injection and so that's why parameters are recommended.

Since you are passing a table name this can be a little more difficult but I think this should give you what you are after:

```
"DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(1000) = N'DELETE FROM ' + @GetTableName + ' WHERE sl = ''1''' EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL"
```

You would then need to add the parameter `@GetTableName` to `SQL.DataUpdate` and assign the value of `txtTableNumber.Text` to it.

Since the string can look a little messy, you may want to consider using a stored procedure to handle this. Again passing the `@GetTableName` parameter.

I'm unsure as to what you have declared `SQL` as. Normally I use the [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) class to execute my SQL. Something like this:

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(connectionString),
      cmd As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(1000) = N'DELETE FROM ' + @GetTableName + ' WHERE sl = ''1''' EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL", con)

    con.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GetTableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTableNumber.Text

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

If you can clarify what `SQL` is I may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: Thanks @Pikoh. For reference (if you were wondering, as I know I do), I didn't downvote yours. I just provided an alternative answer. You'd know if I did, I'd leave a comment.

Comment: Don't worry, i know it probably was @SeanLange, and he was right when he did. Although after my edit i think I don't deserve it, but that's ok :)